# Type Error with const in react in products page

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, react-native, compiler-errors

When I compile the code it is throwing an error below is the error
compiled inside VS Code, using React

[image: Error Image]

Here below is the code in my ProductPage.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { ShopContext } from "../../context/shopContext";
import { Text, Div, Button, Row, Col, Container, Image, ThemeProvider } from "atomize";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { ReactComponent as HeartIcon } from "../../icons/heart.svg";

const theme = {
  grid: {
    colCount: 8,
    gutterWidth: 0
  }
};
const ProductPage = () => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const { fetchProductWithId, addItemToCheckout, product, client } = useContext(
    ShopContext
  );

  const [sizeIndex, setSizeIndex] = useState('');
  const [colorIndex, setColorIndex] = useState('');

  const [favoriteText, setFavoriteText] = useState("Add to Favorite");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductWithId(id);
    return () => {};
  }, [fetchProductWithId, id]);

  if (!product.title) return <div>loading</div>;

  const selectedVariant = client.product.helpers.variantForOptions(product, {
    Size: sizeIndex || product.options[0].values[0].value,
    Color: colorIndex || product.options[1].values[0].value
  });

  return (

    <Container>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Row bg="black" rounded="lg" d="flex"
      m="6rem">
        <Col size={{ xs: 8, lg: 5 }}>
          <Image src={product.images[0].src} w="20rem" p="2rem"/>
        </Col>
        <Col size={{ xs: 8, lg: 3 }} align="space-around" >
          <Text tag="h1" textColor="white" textWeight="200" m={{ y: "2rem" }} >
            {product.title}
          </Text>
          <Text tag="h3" textColor="white" m={{ y: "2rem" }} textWeight="200">
          € {product.variants[0].price}
          </Text>

          <select value={sizeIndex} onChange={e => setSizeIndex(e.target.value)} >
            {product.options[0].values.map((item, index) => (
              <option value={item.value}>{item.value}</option>
            ))
            }
          </select>
          <select value={colorIndex} onChange={e => setColorIndex(e.target.value)} >
            {product.options[1].values.map((item, index) => (
              <option value={item.value}>{item.value}</option>
            ))
            }
          </select>
          
          <Button
            rounded="lg"
            shadow="3"
            bg="black500"
            m={{ y: "2rem" }}
            onClick={() => addItemToCheckout(product.variants[0].id, 1)}
          >
            Add to Cart
          </Button>
          <Button  rounded="lg"
            shadow="3"
            bg="black500"
            m={{ y: "2rem" }}
            onClick={() => {
            // console.log(product);
            let favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites') || "[]");
            const productExists = favorites.find(favorite => favorite.id === product.id);
            if(productExists) {              
              favorites = favorites.filter(favorite => favorite.id !== product.id);
              setFavoriteText("Add to Favorite")
              localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
              
            } else {
              favorites = [...favorites, product];
              setFavoriteText("Remove from Favorite");
              localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
            }

          }}>
             {/* <HeartIcon title="Add to Favourites" style={{height: '25px', width: '25px', backgroundColor: "#fff", color: "red" }} /> */}
            {favoriteText}
          </Button>
         
        </Col>
      </Row>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default ProductPage;
```

Comment: in the shopContext.js

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (!product.title) return <div>loading</div>;

  const selectedVariant = client.product.helpers.variantForOptions(product, {
    Size: sizeIndex || product.options[0].values[0].value,
    Color: colorIndex || product.options[1].values[0].value
  });
```

Your problem is in this part. Since you only return a "loader" if the `title` parameter is undefined and not if the entire `product` object is undefined. Your error clearly states that it is trying to access a parameter on an undefined object, in this case it refers to `product` being undefined.

The solution is to either return the "loader" if `product` is undefined or make sure that `product` is initialized with some default values, so that its never undefined.